Dirac operator on a manifold with boundary
I already asked the question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/475529/dirac-operator-on-a-manifold-with-boundary but did not receive any response maybe someone here can help.

I have been trying to understand construction of Dirac operator on a manifold with boundary. I came across the following paper:
Hijazi, O., Montiel, S. & Roldán, A. Eigenvalue Boundary Problems for the Dirac Operator. Commun. Math. Phys. 231, 375–390 (2002), MR1946443, Zbl 1018.58020. DOI:10.1007/s00220-002-0725-0 or this link without paywall.



I don't understand equation 7 here. The $n$-dimensional Riemannian manifold $M$ has $n-1$-dimensional boundary $\partial M$. $N$ is the normal to the boundary. And $\Gamma(\mathbb{S}M)$ denotes the section of spinor bundle of the manifold $M$. Mentioned after eq. 4 in the paper, they write $D = \gamma^{i} \nabla_{i}$ ($D$ on the RHS of eq. 7) with $i = 1,\ldots, n$. From eq. 7, it looks like we are acting with Levi-Civita connection ($\nabla_{N}$) in the $N$th direction twice. I don't understand why do we do that.
As a 2nd question I wish to consider the simplest example with $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ as the boundary of $\mathbb{R}^{4}$ where, the mean curvature is trivially $0$. If $(w,x,y,z)$ with $w \geq 0$ are coordinates on $\mathbb{R}^{4}$, then say the boundary is at $w=0$. Naively doing this gives some strange operator.
Any help will be appreciated.

